# dealing inconsistencies in a column in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, fuzzywuzzy

I am dealing with inconsistencies in a column. i have a column with list of many names but multiple times with some inconsistencies. I am trying to deal with it using FuzzyWuzzy. I am adding another column which gives most common matches to the name. My code is as below:

```
names = list(data['Name'].unique())

def replace_matches(df, column, matching_string, min_ratio = 90):

    strings = df[column].unique()
    for i in matching_string:
        matches = fuzzywuzzy.process.extract(i, strings, limit= 5, scorer=fuzzywuzzy.fuzz.token_sort_ratio)
        close_matches = [matches[0] for matches in matches if matches[1] >= min_ratio]
        matched_rows = df[column].isin(close_matches)
        df.loc[matched_rows, column] = i
    return df
```

The code is running fine. But my list of name is as follows - Caves, Caves, cabes, Cheras, Cheres.

But the code recommend 'Cabes' for 'Caves' where it should be opposite. I noticed that it is taking the first word alphabetically and using it as reference. How can I change this so that I get 'Caves' as the suggested one

Comment: I have achieved the same by reversing my list of unique names names[: : -1]; but that is not generalizing on all the dataset; any better approach?